# I have this issue with mysqli_escape_string

Tags: sql

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line 33

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0evq.png)

Comment: Please learn about using statements.  Even if what you are doing might be injection proof, it is ugly, hard to read, and, as you're now seeing, error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide database connection as well: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

`mysqli_escape_string($database_connection, $query)`

Also, learn about statements and how to use them. I recommend you to read more about PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks i needed to set up the connection.